# Pyinstaller executable fails on old OS X

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

I have a wxPython GUI packaged into an executable with Pyinstaller.  It works correctly on OS X 10.13.4, but doesn't initialize on OS X 10.12.6.

This is the error output when my executable is run from the command line:

```
[4693] Error loading Python lib '/var/folders/9_/5d_4dfcs4lj11bdjq4twtl5w0000gp/T/_MEIYsEh11/Python': dlopen:   dlopen(/var/folders/9_/5d_4dfcs4lj11bdjq4twtl5w0000gp/T/_MEIYsEh11/Python, 10): Symbol not found: _futimens
Referenced from: /var/folders/9_/5d_4dfcs4lj11bdjq4twtl5w0000gp/T/_MEIYsEh11/Python (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
in /var/folders/9_/5d_4dfcs4lj11bdjq4twtl5w0000gp/T/_MEIYsEh11/Python
```

I have no idea what this error message means.  I've tried googling some pieces of it, but I'm not getting any meaningful results.

I'm looking for any clue to get me going in the right direction -- what might be wrong, or how to debug.  Unfortunately I don't have access to OS X 10.12.6, so I'm having to troubleshoot for a user remotely.

This is my version of Pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller 3.4.dev0+g07ab024c
```

This seems to happen with brew-installed Python or Anaconda.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but it has happened to me as well. After a bit of research, as per the documentation:
https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#making-mac-os-x-apps-forward-compatible

Basically you'll need to install a virtual machine with the oldest OS you'd like support (say, osx maverick, or ubuntu 16) with the complete development environment and run pyinstaller there. As of the time of writing, there seems to be no way around it.

Comment: Yes, I found the same.  Annoyingly, getting old versions of OSX (through legitimate channels) turned out to be nearly impossible.

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to have already installed it previously to find it in the history, otherwise it won't let you download the image. You'd need to ask someone else that has it to download it for you. Otherwise checkout nuitka.net, it's a totally different way, but can create packages from any host OS